# Bash shebang option -l

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

I use a script, `test.sh`, written by someone else, the begins with a bash shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
...
echo TEST: $TEST
```

From what I could see, this has an effect on variables used inside the script:

- if I run `TEST=hey ./test.sh`, I can see `TEST: hop`, `hop` being the value of variable `TEST` in my `.bash_profile`
- this is the same if I `export TEST=hey` before running the script
- but if I remove the `-l` flag, the same command returns `TEST: hey`, as I would have expected

Can someone please explain this behaviour ? The help of bash did not... help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `-l` option (according to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)) makes "bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell".  Login shells read certain initialization files from your home directory, such as `.bash_profile`.  Since you set the value of `TEST` in your `.bash_profile`, the value you set on the command line gets overridden when `bash` launches.