# Could not find rake using whenever rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, whenever

Hello I have a strange problem, I'm trying to get rake task working in whenever, but have this problem `Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`. It's strange, because it searches this rake version in ruby 2.1.2 version `/home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92`. However I'm using ruby 2.2.0 in rvm and the gem list is also using that version.
It's a simple cron job:

```
every 1.minute do
  rake 'process_email:handle', output: 'log/mail.log', environment: 'development'
end
```

Rakefile:

```
namespace :process_email do
  desc 'Handle email'
  task handle: :environment do
    MOBIZARD_MAILER.processor.retrieve_mail
  end
end
```

Mobizard mailer is my own gem, that retrieves mails through ruby mail gem, that uses same ruby 2.2.0 and same gem list.
Whole stack trace in mail.log looks like this:

```
/home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vyivrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Thx for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the output is set with the `-l` flag, which is incorrectly interpreted by rvm.

You can read more about this issue here:

https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/325

Comment: Nothing in the link made any sense to me.  I did not learn what the "-l" flag is, where it is being called, by what, or how to include or exclude it.

Comment: This could for sure use more detail

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Add this to `schedule.rb`

```
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }
```

Ref: https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/656

---

My guess is the `GEM_PATH` is not the same when running in a crontab and when running in your normal/dev environment. You could check it which this command

```
gem which rake
```

In my cases:

- When running in crontab `GEM_PATH` would be something like `/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundle`
- When running in "normal", the `GEM_PATH` is `/usr/local/bundle`

This script `ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }` will auto add those envs to make sure ruby using the right `GEM_PATH`

---

Quote from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499839/1819549

> The -l option (according to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)) makes "bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell". Login shells read certain initialization files from your home directory, such as `.bash_profile`. Since you set the value of TEST in your `.bash_profile`, the value you set on the command line gets overridden when bash launches.

So  @Yury's answer works maybe because the command executes something in `.bash_profile` and I guess it update the GEM_PATH for rvm.