# GemNotFound rake when using whenever in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundle, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever

I'm getting this one error I don't understand (I'm fairly new to rails) when using the gem 'whenever' in development mode.

What I did was update config/schedule.rb and run

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

crontab -l lists:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/vic/Desktop/WorkflowProject && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''Task.new2'\'' >> log/whenever.log 2>&1'
```

at config/schedule.rb

```
set :output, 'log/whenever.log'

every 1.minute do
  runner "Task.new2"
end
```

at log/whenever.log

```
bundler: failed to load command: bin/rails (bin/rails)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Your bundle is locked to rake (11.3.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (11.3.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (11.3.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
/home/vic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/vic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I would grealy appreciate the help, thank you very much!

Comment: Victor, found any solution then update here so helpful to another users. I have same issue. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands.

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

Ref: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722642/error-running-bundle-command)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have `bundler` installed? Try running `bundle install` inside your application directory.
If no, see Jayaprakash's answer above.
If yes, try `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'`.

Update:
Ahh, missed that you are seeing error when your task executes.
Try this in your config/schedule.rb

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, "#{ Whenever.path }/log/whenever.log"

every 1.minute do
  runner "Task.new2"
end
```

Comment: I'm new to rails so I suppose if my 'bundle install' executes correctly then my bundler is installed. In fact, it did execute. I tried running the command you specified and the crontab file was updated to look exactly like the one I posted. The error persists.

Comment: @VictorSprengel Updated my answer.

Comment: I updated my schedule.rb as suggested and updated the crontab (which now contains the PATH). The error still persists (exactly).

Comment: This seems to resemble with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118033/could-not-find-rake-using-whenever-rails.